# Service still working after deleting catalina.properties

Tags: tomcat, service, catalina

I've been running a service (java, spring batch, tomcat) for some time now. Then I deleted the catalina.properties file to test some stuff, and suprise! everything still works the same. I was able to run the service, complete a job and so on.

How is that possible? Since the catalina properties file holds all the configuration for database access.. driver, security, etc.

I tried right clicking on the server, Clean and Clean Tomcat work dir, nothing changed.

**Edit:** Weirdly enough, I found the same properties file in `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf` even though I did not put it there. Why is that?

**Edit2: What I've noticed:**

So my properties are stored in `workspace\Servers\Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config`.

Eclipse apparently only uses the ones from `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf` . If I delete these, when I publish the server, the normal ones are just copied here and again used from here.

So in order to make it fail, I have to delete the files from both locations. Is this some kind of a caching mechanism? Can it be stopped?

Comment: Are you certain that the `catalina.properties` you deleted is the one being used by Tomcat?  Do a high-level search for the file `catalina.properties` and be prepared for a surprise.  Either this, or by strange luck the default settings are working for you.

Comment: you were right. see edit

Comment: Are you using a standard Tomcat app server?  Which version is it?

Comment: yes, standard. v7.0.50

Comment: and eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *partial* answer.  I say "partial" because I have an explanation but only a partial solution as I am not an Eclipse guru.

When you launch Tomcat from your IDE, Eclipse is using the properties file found in `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf` instead of using the properties file located in `C:\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.x\conf`.  One way to immediately get around this problem is to launch Tomcat from a command prompt using `catalina start`.  This should start Tomcat using `catalina.properties` from the usual default location.

Comment: I've added a new Edit